# ignore specific command from zsh completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Is it possible to tell `zsh` to not autocomplete certain commands when using <kbd>TAB</kbd> completion ?

EXAMPLE:

I type `chm <tab>` and zsh completion offers me two options:

```
chmem  chmod
```

I never use `chmem`. Instead of having two options, I would prefer to have `chm` automatically completed to `chmod`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' ignored-patterns 'chmem'
```

---

If you needed to do more than one ignored pattern, you would do it like this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' ignored-patterns 'chmem|chcpu|chcon'
```

Comment: perfect. that works. thanks a lot

Comment: @Gilles - my list of `ignored-patterns` has gotten quite large. Is it possible to save the list in a file, and specify `zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' ignored-patterns /PATH/TO/FILE' ?

Comment: @MartinVegter Assuming the file contains one element per line: `… "${(@f)$(</PATH/TO/FILE)}"`